# Hide a field in munin graph

Tags: munin

In my new server, a sensor for the ACPI plugin reports 0 K (-273.15 C) as temperature. So, the graph is absolutely useless as this temperature (absolute zero, obviously wrong) makes all the other temps to look flat.

According the documentation it's possible to disable a field, by writing

`thermal_zone2.graph no`

in `munin.conf`, but it isn't working. How can i disable that graph? Or otherwise force the y axis minimum to 0° C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find how to disable that graph, i even tried with a config file in `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d` but no luck.

So i just edited the plugin itself.

In `/usr/share/munin/plugins/acpi` find the command that enumerates the thermal zones,

```
ATZ=$(find /sys/class/thermal/ -maxdepth 1 -name "thermal_zone*" | sort -V)
```

In my server, the first thermal zones have invalid values, so i just replaced it with

```
ATZ=$(find /sys/class/thermal/ -maxdepth 1 -name "thermal_zone[3-6]" | sort -V)
```

so the plugin only lists the "valid" thermal zones.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for the `sensors_` plugin, edit or create `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/sensors.conf` and place this in it:

```
[sensors_*]
  env.ignore_temp3 yes
  env.ignore_temp4 yes
  env.ignore_temp5 yes
  env.ignore_fan5  yes
```

and include the relevant type/number.  Note that running `sudo munin-run sensors_temp` will still show the value, but running `sudo munin-run sensors_temp config` will show the following at the end of the output:

```
temp4.graph no
```

...and the value will not be graphed